# how can I trigger an onload from a script included in a jquery plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, onload

I'm writing a jquery plugin. I have a script tag that's dynamically added for LivePerson.com. The script, once loaded, is supposed to trigger and onLoad function defined in the config. However this never fires. I'm curious if its a problem with timing maybe, since the plugin is initiated on doc ready and the script is added when the window loads? Any ideas?

```
jQuery(function(){
jQuery(document).easyChat({
    popup: false,
    siteId:'XXXXXXXXX',
    appKey: 'XXXXXXXXX'
});
});
```

Plugin Script:

```
;(function($, document, window, undefined) {
// Optional, but considered best practice by some
"use strict";

// Name the plugin so it's only in one place
var pluginName = 'easyChat';
var lpc;

// Default options for the plugin as a simple object
var defaults = {
    popup : true,
    skill: 'Test'
};

// Plugin constructor
// This is the boilerplate to set up the plugin to keep our actual logic in one place
function Plugin(element, options) {
    this.element = element;

    // Merge the options given by the user with the defaults
    this.options = $.extend({}, defaults, options)

    // Initialization code to get the ball rolling
    // If your plugin is simple, this may not be necessary and
    // you could place your implementation here
    if(this.options.popup != true){
        this.init();
    } else {
        this.popup();
    }
}

Plugin.prototype = {
    // Public functions accessible to users
    // Prototype methods are shared across all elements
    // You have access to this.options and this.element

    popup:function(){
        console.log("popup");
    },

    DoAChat:function(){
        lpc = new lpChat();
        lpc.chatAvailability(); 

        // alert('Before');
      //  lpc.requestChat();
        // alert('After');
        if(this.options.popup == true){

        } else {
        //  document.getElementById('status').innerHTML += ' Done!';
        }
    },

    myOnLoad:function() {
         console.log("LP JS API Initiated");
        this.DoAChat();
    },

    myOnInit:function() {

    },

    myOnStart:function() {

    },

    myOnStop:function() {

    },

    myOnState:function() {

    },

    myOnTyping:function() {

    },

    myOnPush:function() {

    },

    myOnLine:function() {

    },

    myOnError:function() {

    },

    myOnAvailability:function(availObj) {
    console.log(availObj);
    },

    myOnResume:function() {

    },

    myOnAccountToAccountTransfer:function() {

    },

    //First Method triggered from plugin init
    init: function() {
       var lpChatConfig = {
        apiKey : this.options.appKey,lpNumber : this.options.siteId,  
        lpServer: 'dev.liveperson.net',
        onLoad : this.myOnLoad,  
        onInit : this.myOnInit,
        onStart : this.myOnStart,  
        onStop : this.myOnStop,
        onState : this.myOnState,  
        onAgentTyping : this.myOnTyping,
        onUrlPush : this.myOnPush,  
        onLine : this.myOnLine,
        onError : this.myOnError,  
        onAvailability: this.myOnAvailability,
        onResume : this.myOnResume,  
        onAccountToAccountTransfer: this.myOnAccountToAccountTransfer,
        skill: this.options.skill
        };

        lpChatConfig.lpAddScript = function(src, ignore) {var c = lpChatConfig;if(typeof(c.lpProtocol)=='undefined'){c.lpProtocol = (document.location.toString().indexOf("https:")==0) ? "https" : "http";}if (typeof(src) == 'undefined' || typeof(src) == 'object') {src = c.lpChatSrc ? c.lpChatSrc : '/hcp/html/lpChatAPI.js';};if (src.indexOf('http') != 0) {src = c.lpProtocol + "://" + c.lpServer + src + '?site=' + c.lpNumber;} else {if (src.indexOf('site=') < 0) {if (src.indexOf('?') < 0)src = src + '?'; else src = src + '&';src = src + 'site=' + c.lpNumber;}};var s = document.createElement('script');s.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');s.setAttribute('charset', 'iso-8859-1');s.setAttribute('src', src);document.getElementsByTagName('head').item(0).appendChild(s);}
if (window.attachEvent) window.attachEvent('onload', lpChatConfig.lpAddScript);
else window.addEventListener('load', lpChatConfig.lpAddScript, false);





    }



};

$.fn[pluginName] = function(options) {
    // Iterate through each DOM element and return it
    return this.each(function() {
        // prevent multiple instantiations
        if (!$.data(this, 'plugin_' + pluginName)) {
            $.data(this, 'plugin_' + pluginName, new Plugin(this, options));
        }
    });
};

// Private function that is only called by the plugin
var privateFunction = function() {
    // ...
}

})(jQuery, document, window);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you referring to your `myOnLoad` function not being called? I don't see anywhere in your quoted code where myOnLoad is called, only its definition and aliases to it. Your `lpChatConfig` defines an `onLoad` attribute that is a reference to `myOnLoad`, but you never call that either. `window.attachEvent('onload', lpChatConfig.lpAddScript)` is going to attach execution to the window's onload event to lpChatConfig.lpAddScript. Perhaps you want to have lpChatConfig.lpAddScript execute lpChatConfig.onLoad?